# Python: changing directory name at FTP server for downloading the file

Tags: python

I am trying to download a file from FTP server. I am able to connect to the server. But not able to change the directory.

```
#! /user/bin/python33
import os
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.sec.gov")
ftp.login("anonymous", "abcd@yahoo.com")
data = []
ftp.dir(data.append)
ftp.quit()
for line in data:
    print( "-", line)
print(os.getcwd())
path= "/edgar/full-index/2013/"
print(path)
ftp.cwd(path)
```

it fails in the last line. can some one suggest what needs to be done"
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `it failes in the last line` - what fails? Paste the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cwd` call fails because you previously called `ftp.quit()`.

[The docs for that method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.quit) say:

> Send a QUIT command to the server and close the connection. This is the “polite” way to close a connection, but it may raise an exception if the server responds with an error to the QUIT command. This implies a call to the close() method which renders the FTP instance useless for subsequent calls (see below).

(The "below" reference is to the next part of the documentation which says you can't do any operations on a closed FTP object.)